# Solving a System of Equations and Inequalities

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of two (large) equations in two variables: phi and theta. The equations are defined below.

```
GaussCurvature[f_] := 
  With[{dfθ = D[f, θ], dfϕ = D[f, ϕ]}, 
   Simplify[(Det[{D[dfθ, θ], dfθ, 
          dfϕ}] Det[{D[dfϕ, ϕ], dfθ, 
          dfϕ}] - 
       Det[{D[f, θ, ϕ], dfθ, 
          dfϕ}]^2)/(dfθ.dfθ dfϕ.dfϕ - \
(dfθ.dfϕ)^2)^2]];
```

```
SphericalHarmonic[ℓ_, m_] := 
 ComplexExpand[
  Re[SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ, m, θ, ϕ]]]
```

```
DθGC [ℓ_, m_, n_: 1] := 
 D[GaussCurvature[
   FromSphericalCoordinates[{SphericalHarmonic[ℓ, m], θ, ϕ}]], {θ, n}]

D\[Phi]GC [ℓ_, m_, n_: 1] := 
 D[GaussCurvature[
   FromSphericalCoordinates[{SphericalHarmonic[ℓ, m], θ, ϕ}]], {ϕ, n}]
```

I use the following to solve for the solutions to the system of equations:

```
CritCandidates[ℓ_, m_] := 
 Simplify[Solve[{DθGC[ℓ, m] == 0, 
    DϕGC[ℓ, m] == 0}, {θ, ϕ}]]
```

This returns a list of ConditionalExpressions:

```
{
{θ -> ConditionalExpression[-(π/2) + 2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers],
 ϕ -> ConditionalExpression[-((π C[2])/3), C[2] ∈ Integers]},
{θ -> ConditionalExpression[-(π/2) + 2 π C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers],
 ϕ -> ConditionalExpression[-(1/6) π (1 + 2 C[2]), C[2] ∈ Integers]},
...
}
```

What I really want is the solutions to the above system of equations subject to the additional domain restrictions that:

```
0<=θ<=π
0<=ϕ<2π
```

but when I add them to the system above:

```
CritCandidates[ℓ_, m_] := 
 Simplify[Solve[{DθGC[ℓ, m] == 0, 
    DϕGC[ℓ, m] == 0,0<=θ<=π,0<=ϕ<2π}, {θ, ϕ}]]
```

I get

```
'This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.'
```

I find it hard to believe that Mathematica can handle the system of equations but cannot synthesize those results with the additional domain criteria inequalities. Can anyone explain why this error occurs and how I can work around it?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've corrected that typo.

Comment: The only workaround I have come up with so far extracts the expressions and exploits the expressions' monotonicity and parameterization over integers to find bounds explicitly. It seems very un-Mathematica.